# nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument ubuntu ec2

Tags: nginx, config, pid

i run `systemctl status nginx` i see this in the log  `nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument`

i run `ps aux -P | grep nginx`

root     30696  0.0  0.1 141260  1632 ?        Ss   16:00   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data 33701  0.0  0.7 1234344 7116 ?        S    16:00   0:00 nginx: worker process
ubuntu   31115  0.0  0.1  12344 1128 pts/0    S+   16:00   0:00 grep --color=auto ngin

this is my config nginx.

```
`user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}
http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        server {

        listen 443;

        ssl on;

        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl/certificati/nginx_bundle_af1458631462.crt;

        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl/my.domain.key;

        root /var/www/path;

        server_name my.domain.com;

        }
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue with `/run/nginx.pid`.

You can try these 2 steps.

- Check if the path `/run/nginx.pid` exists and if not, or create it
  with the correct permissions.
- Check the permissions and ownership of the directory
  `/run/nginx.pid`. The Nginx should have a write permissions to the
  file and its parent directory.